# Can't make use of newly produced links in a function

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

When i run my scraper it fetches titles and hrefs to the titles form a webpage. The page has pagination option in the footer which contains 6 new links which are being scraped by the second "print" in my scraper. But, at this point I can't make use of this next-page links, I meant I can't find any way to insert it somewhere in the function so that I can grab the titles and hrefs from each next-page link. Sorry for any mistakes I've made and thanks in advance to take a look into it.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Page_link="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"

def GrabbingData(url):
    base="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk"
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    title = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/text()')
    link = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]/a/@href')
    for i,j in zip(title,link):
        print(i,j) 

    pagination=tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' woPaging ')]//a[@class='woPagingItem' or @class='woPagingNext']/@href")
    for nextp in pagination:
        print(base + nextp)

GrabbingData(Page_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make it a recursive function, like this:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Page_link="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
visited_links = []

def GrabbingData(url):
    base="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk"
    response = requests.get(url)
    visited_links.append(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    title = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]//a/text()')
    link = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]//a/@href')
    for i,j in zip(title,link):
        print(i,j)

    pagination=tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' woPaging ')]//a[@class='woPagingItem' or @class='woPagingNext']/@href")
    for nextp in pagination:
        url1 = str(base + nextp)
        if url1 not in visited_links:
            #print(url1)
            GrabbingData(url1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GrabbingData(Page_link)
```

Since the HTML on a next page URL will contain "Back" links, I also added a list *visited_links*, so you don't go back to pages already visited and you don't end up with infinite loop.

The last part starting with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

is commonly used to call a function if the file is called directly (as opposed to being imported).

Comment: Thanks dear Lukáš Říha, for your effective solution. This is exactly what I was after.